# Adding id to dynamically generated table before appending to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-table

I am creating a table as below in my Javascript:

```
var l_table = op.script.table_dom_start + op.script.l_table_header + l_table_rows + op.script.table_dom_end;
```

Which results in:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
   <tr>
     <th class="capitalize">
       ...
     </th>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Which is then `appended` to target div:

```
$(l_table).appendTo('#l-ajax-response-div');
```

Now, before appending, I want to give this class an `id` and tried below ways:

```
$(l_table).attr('id', 'l-entry-table');
```

and

```
l_table.id='l-entry-table';
```

Both of these fail to work, what is going on here?

Variable contents:

```
table_dom_start: '<table class="table table-hover">',
header: specific header for that table
row: specific rows for that table
table_dom_end: '</table>',
```

Comment: `id` attribute starting with number?..... I don't think this is supported... I mean it's a bad practice... you can't give css.

Comment: its `l` not `1`, `l` for London~ :)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var mytable=$(l_table);
mytable[0].id="l-entry-table";
mytable.appendTo('#l-ajax-response-div');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this below example it will alert no of tables found by id.

```js
var l_table = '<table class="table table-hover"><tr><th class="capitalize">Table with ID</th></tr></table>';

$(l_table).attr('id', 'l-entry-table').appendTo('#l-ajax-response-div');

alert($('#l-entry-table').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="l-ajax-response-div"></div>
```

Comment: Have you executed code snippet. It's working the way i have showed.
You might be trying to put in separate lines for adding id and appending.

Comment: May i know which jQuery version you are using? Because if above snippet alerts 1 then it is working